# Location of theme options page menu icon

Tags: theme-development, theme-options, icon

Hi this may look a little silly question but can someone let me know where is the location for  theme_path? is it inside my own theme or very top level of the directory?

```
'menu_icon'  => theme_path . '/images/product-icon.png',
```

**A**: www.awebsite.com/images/product-icon.png 
**B**: www.awebsite.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/product-icon.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you are referring to here. Judging from your code `theme_path` looks like a constant.

Usually when supplying/printing links to theme assets you would use `get_bloginfo('key')` with one of the keys `template_directory` or `stylesheet_directory`. Basically the latter will point at the child theme and the first to the parent theme if you are using a child/parent setup. Otherwise they are identical. Alternatively you could use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` or `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` which behaves the same way.

In any case, they will return `http://www.yoursite.com/path/to/wordpress/wp-content/themes/your-theme/`, and you are responsible for appending the path with `'/images/product-icon.png'` or whatever is appropriate. Thus, alternative B in your question is correct.

**One side note**: WordPress generally uses the terms *uri* or *url* when referring to content your browsers will load, and the term *path* when referring to files on the servers local file system (i.e. resources that WordPress/PHP will load in itself).

Comment: Thanks Simon, what I am trying to do is creating a "Custom Page Type" and setting a menu_icon for that.As you know I am registering the page in function.php page, so what should I do now?

Comment: Change the line in your example into `'menu_icon'  => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/product-icon.png'` and it should workout fine, given that you have directory called `images` inside your theme holding the file `product-icon.png`.

Comment: Glad I could help!